# compaction strategies and high performance storage

Tags: cassandra

My apologies for this being a somewhat newbie question. However, my understanding of Cassandra is that is use three different compaction strategies:

- are these tunable, or is this area a black box, i.e. there is nothing you can tweak,
- if compaction can be tweaked are there any recommendations for high performance flash storage, the reason I ask is because I have come across comments in blogs etc  suggesting that "Compaction can be rough on flash storage".